# Decreasing staged rollout percentage in Google Play

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Can we release an app update in Google Play dev console to 99% of users, and then reduce it to 50%?
I know about halt option, but that's not the same and we're interested specifically in decreasing % of new installs that'll receive the new version.

Thanks.

Comment: Just found out that you can actually do this (in the sense that the UI lets you do it). I'm wondering if its real (how are they handling downgrading app version? Isn't it dangerous?) or if its a bug. Maybe they are effectively stopping the rollout (no more updats) and all new installs download the "old" version until the % is met?

Comment: Also, AFAIK if you halt the staged rollout then no new installs will receive the new version. Isn't that what you want? See: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en#zippy=%2Chalt-a-staged-rollout

Comment: Some extra info - at 99% it has taken my roll-out 3 days to reach 25% of the 'install base'.  You can halt the roll-out at any time, so with 99% you still have very good control - and you reach your desired percentage quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question: **yes**, you can decrease percentage of the staged roll out (however if the stage rollout is 99% and changed it to 98%, only 98% of the users will receive the staged rollout version).

Be careful though because although you can modify the percentage of the stage rollout in Google Play Console UI, it is not recommended to reduce or decrease the percentage s it's not guaranteed that all users will be affected with the changes if they have already installed the app prior to rolling back to a lower percentage.

But you probably wanted to ask something different.

Can I downgrade already upgraded applications? **No**, you can't.

You can only halt updating. But what's already updated is updated.